# How to upgrade from Mac OS X v10.5.8 to 10.6.4?

Tags: mac, osx-snow-leopard, upgrade

How do I upgrade from Mac OS X v10.5.8 to 10.6.4 ?

I have a Mac mini with Mac OS X v10.5.8. Now I want to upgrade it to Mac OS X v10.6.4. How can I do that?

Do I really need an original Mac OS X DVD? Or is it possible to download a Mac OS X disc image and upgrade it?

Comment: Don't forget to mark an answer as "accepted" to help other users who find your question.

Answer (score 2):

Actually the upgrade is only $29 if you're upgrading from Leopard (10.5.xx) Information about [OS X 10.6 can be found here](http://www.apple.com/macosx/)

Apple has not offered any option to download the upgrade.

Answer (score 1):

Upgrading from Leopard (10.5) to Snow Leopard (10.6) is an upgrade for which you have to purchase the DVD. (It's a bit cheaper than the previous upgrades as far as I remember.)